# SQL varbinay(max) column not saving image

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I have a problem saving an image from ASP.NET webforms showing data in SQL Server database table

```
0x000
```

My code to save the image in ASP.NET page is:

```vb
Dim Stream As IO.Stream
Dim FileLen As Integer
Dim FileOK As Boolean = False
Dim dt As New Data.DataTable
Dim SqlStr As String = String.Empty

If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
    Dim FileExtension As String, FileSize As Integer, Height As Integer, Width As Integer
    FileSize = FileUpload1.FileBytes.Count() / 1024
    FileExtension = IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower()

    Dim Img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
    Height = Img.Height
    Width = Img.Width

    If FileSize <= 100 Then
        If Width <= 700 AndAlso Height <= 500 Then
            If FileExtension = ".jpg" Or FileExtension = ".png" Or FileExtension = ".jpeg" Then
                FileOK = True
            Else
                FileOK = False
            End If

            If FileOK Then
                FileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength
                Dim fltp As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
                Dim MyData(FileLen) As Byte
                Stream = FileUpload1.FileContent
                Stream.Read(MyData, 0, FileLen)
                Dim decfileparameter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ImgBinary", Data.SqlDbType.Binary)
                decfileparameter.Value = MyData
                Dim Action As Integer = 1
                SqlStr = "SaveUpdateSubServicesToMaster '" & Action & "','" & ddServiceTypeName.SelectedValue & "','" & TxtSubServiceName.Text & "','" & TxtPriceB4Txt.Text & "','" & TxtBasicPrice.Text & "','" & TxtAfterPrice.Text & "','" & TxtAboutSrvc.Text & "','" & TxtTrunTime.Text & "','" & TxtFinalBill.Text & "','" & TxtDuration.Text & "','" & DDIsSerAvl.SelectedValue & "','0',@ImgBinary"
                Dim sqlConnString As String = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NewSHCService").ConnectionString
                Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(sqlConnString)
                Dim sqlcmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SqlStr, con)
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(decfileparameter)
                con.Open()
                Using sdr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dt.Load(sdr)
                End Using
                con.Close()
```

as when storing data trough stored procedure taking `varbinary(max)` to insert data into table.

But it is not saving the image.

When I directly store image through

```sql
UPDATE dbo.ServiceSubTypeMaster 
SET ServiceSubTypeImage = (SELECT BulkColumn 
                           FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\TanDev\Desktop\Imgs_New_Shc_Services\SameSize\134.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X)
WHERE ServiceSubTypeID = 137
```

it's showing image properly.

Comment: I don't think it's showing `0x000` since that's 1 1/2 bytes. Instead of using `SqlDbType.Binary` without a length specifier try using `SqlDbType.VarBinary` with a length specifier of `-1` (which signifies "max").

Comment: Time to develop GOOD coding habits. You can declare your variables anywhere in your code - but why do that and FORCE the reader to search through the densely formatted code to find the declarations? And perhaps providing feedback when your code block does nothing might be useful to the caller or to the GUI? Lastly USE PARAMETERIZED SQL statements for all the parameters - not just some. Your code is wide-open to sql injection.

Comment: @SMor, I do agree with you that there is a heap that can be done here to tidy up the code, I'm not in 100% agreement  about where to put declarations.  To me it makes sense to declare variables where they are needed.  Think about big procedures, scrolling around to find your declarations, then back to the code etc.  Probably more of a style thing that a straight best practice